# How to convert Unicode text into a Bitmap

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, drawtext, drawstring

I need to convert a text containing Unicode chars into a Bitmap that could have a transparent background as well.
I found and tried different posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838037/drawing-text-to-a-bitmap-with-textrenderer), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311545/c-sharp-write-text-on-bitmap), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348042/converting-from-string-to-image-in-c-sharp), but no one seems to work for me.
I found also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4128985/4396321) that suggests using *TextRenderer.DrawText()* method instead of *System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawString()* but the final result is not good anyway.

That's a code snippet:

```
private static Bitmap ImageFromText(string text, Font font, Color textColor, Color fillColor, System.Drawing.Graphics graphics)
{
    Bitmap bmpOut;

    SizeF sz = TextRenderer.MeasureText(graphics, text, font);
    //SizeF sz = g.MeasureString(text, font);

    if (sz.IsEmpty)

        sz = new SizeF(1, 1);

    bmpOut = new Bitmap((int) Math.Ceiling(sz.Width), (int) Math.Ceiling(sz.Height), PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    using (System.Drawing.Graphics gBmp = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bmpOut))
    {
        gBmp.Clear(fillColor);

        gBmp.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        gBmp.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;
        gBmp.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;

        //gBmp.DrawString(text, font, brFore, 0, 0); // Unicode chars are not supported
        TextRenderer.DrawText(gBmp, text, font, new Point(0, 0), textColor);
    }

    return bmpOut;
}
```

Here is my test code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();                
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        string testString = "Unicode Title \uD83E\uDC25";
        var font = new Font(new FontFamily("Microsoft Sans Serif"), 12.375f);

        // e.Graphics.DrawString(testString, new Font(font.FontFamily, 20), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 0, 0);

        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, testString, new Font ( font.FontFamily, 20 ), new Point(0, 50), Color.Black);

        Bitmap bitmap = ImageFromText(testString, new Font(font.FontFamily, 20), Color.Black, this.BackColor, e.Graphics);

        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, new Point(0, 100));                

        //Clipboard.SetImage(bitmap);

        
    }
}
```

And this is the poor result:

[image]

How can I improve the bitmap result?

**EDIT**

Short recap:

- I can't use System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawString() method because it does not support Unicode chars
- I can't use TextRenderer.DrawText() method because TextRenderer class uses GDI and it isn't alpha aware, so it does not support a transparent background.

Is there some other way to reach my goal?

Comment: Is the problem the aliasing of the text when drawing to a bitmap compared to drawing to screen? You might want to make that clearer in the title/description.

Comment: You do realize that your bitmap has only screen resolution. TextRenderer can draw nicely onto controls, not Bitmaps.. What is the purpose of the bitmap??

Comment: I need the bitmap because it's what is used in my custom control for handling some text rendering. It not seems only an antialiasing problem. Anyway I need to obtain an image as much similar as possible to the original text.